# assignement of variable ignore after db.commit() in an if condition

Tags: python, html, flask, web

I'm trying to write a web app with Flask. I wrote a  in HTML page and this form use POST method for send data to a python function.

HTML code:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('food')}}">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="food-name">Food Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="food-name" id="food-name" placeholder="Food Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="protein">Protein</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="protein" id="protein" placeholder="Protein">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="carbohydrates">Carbohydrates</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="carbohydrates" id="carbohydrates" placeholder="Carbohydrates">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="fat">Fat</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="fat" id="fat" placeholder="Fat">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
              </form>
```

Python function in my flask app:

```
'''
```

@app.route('/food', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def food():
db = get_db()

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.form['food-name']
    protein = int(request.form['protein'])
    carbohydrates = int(request.form['carbohydrates'])
    fat = int(request.form['fat'])

    calories = protein * 4 + carbohydrates * 4 + fat * 9
    
    db.execute('INSERT INTO food (name, protein, carbohydrates, fat, calories) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', \
        [name, protein, carbohydrates, fat, calories])
    db.commit()


    cur = db.execute('SELECT * FROM food')
    results = cur.fetchall()

return render_template('add_food.html', results=results)
```

'''

And the python function return a HTML list of data stored in database, using a python loop embedded in the HTML code that uses the results variable as a condition :

```html
<div class="page-header"></div>
              {% for food in results %}
              <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a>{{food.name}}</a></li>
                <li><a>Protein: <span class="badge">{{food.protein}}</span></a></li>
                <li><a>Carbohydrates: <span class="badge">{{food.carbohydrates}}</span></a></li>
                <li><a>Fat: <span class="badge">{{food.fat}}</span></a></li>
                <li><a>Calories: <span class="badge">{{food.calories}}</span></a></li>
              </ul> <br>
              {% endfor %}
```

But the variable results after condition if is not assigned and python raise UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment.
I suppose it's fault to db.commit() who should act like break key word.

what do you think ? there is an error in the code ?

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't see any error at first sight. Is this url used only for POST requirements? If it is accessed directly (with GT request) the if statement will not work and results will not be valid
Try to declare results outside the if statement. Also have you tried to print(results) to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, this url is used only for POST requirements. I tried to declare results outside the if statement and it's work but I don't understand why... and I tried to print(results) and python raise the same error (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment).